# How should I combine “typical” and “yesterday” self-reports?

Tags: logistic, references, survey, spatial, calibration

I have inherited a long-running survey with two measures of individual behavior.

**Edits**: clarifying that this is not about drinking behavior; it’s not, and I only used that to try and illustrate. It should apply to any kind of behavior on a daily/weekly timescale, like recycling, burning wood in a fireplace, watching a movie, etc. And I’m not seeking help with this actual analysis. I’m seeking help identifying references or examples similar to this analysis/problem, so I can learn from those. Also clarifying that terms for certain covariates are included (`...`).

OK, on to the problem statement.

1. In the survey, there is a question to elicit a characterization of “typical” behavior: about how many days per week do you typically do X (drink, burn wood, watch a movie, etc.)?
2. Then the follow-up is, did you do X yesterday?
3. There is also a question to obtain the participant’s ZIP code.

The previous analyst fit a logistic model like:

```
X_yesterday ~ X_per_week + ...
```

Where `X_yesterday` is binary and `X_per_week` is 1, 2, … or 7 day/wk. People who responded “never” were held out of the regression, as far more than half reported “never.” None of these respondents have ever reported doing X yesterday. He treated `X_per_week` as a numeric vector. I have experimented with treating it as a factor. The results are similar: there is some apparent nonlinearity, but not enough data, I think, to decide whether a linear model (on the logit scale —– or on the response scale, for that matter) is really more appropriate or not. The additional terms (`...`) include things like whether yesterday was a holiday, a weekend, etc.

The analyst then used the fitted values for subsequent analyses, involving scaling by other quantities followed by ZIP-level aggregation. (At this point the “never” group is folded back in, because the overall rates are supposed to include them.)

This seems useful because a primary goal is to estimate ZIP-level rates, including for ZIP codes where no respondents reported doing X yesterday (on the order of 20% of ZIP codes).

It also seems useful because, taking the “yesterday” question as a gold standard measurement, it turns out that people overstate their *typical* frequency of doing X by something on the order of 10–30%.

*I would like to learn more about calibrating self-reports of typical behavior in this way.* Can you recommend good examples or references? If it’s not obvious, I’m not a statistician, but I am fluent in R. Toy problems are just fine, although I’m happy to provide more details if it would help identify real-world applications that are closer to the true nature and scale of this dataset. Diagnostic tips would also be welcome. Of note, the previous analyst did not exploit spatial correlation (ZIP codes) in any way.

* Simplified, as it’s actually a set of questions, but the end result is an estimated frequency / proportion (days per week). There is also a question analogous to “how much X do you do, when you do X” but let’s hold that aside for now?

Comment: There's a standard alcohol use questionnaire. Is this just an exploratory anaylsis?

Comment: What is x/week a number or a factor in the regression? Assuming you have sufficient data, I would suggest a factor, believing the relationship nonlinear

Comment: You don't explain how you are aggregating at zip code level, but dropping the never group sounds wrong

Comment: "*It also seems useful because, taking the “yesterday” question as a gold standard measurement, it turns out that people overstate their typical frequency of doing X by something on the order of 10–30%.*": you should find a way to control for the day where respondents answered the survey. For instance, depending on their cultural background, many people may be more likely to drink (or other leisure activities) during week-ends or holidays than during a working day.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but all of the example behaviours you've listed (especially alcohol consumption) will have huge day-of-week effects, so asking "did you do X yesterday?" introduces a huge bias based on when the survey is completed. "Did you do X *in the last 7 days*?" or "Over the past 7 days, on how many days did you do X?"

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure what your question is, are you just asking for tips and pointers to resources?